# 1.9 Paypal Express get order review before redirect to paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express, paypal-standard

I was searching for days to find a solution for this problem. I've read a lot about this problem but for me it seems like nobody ever solved it.

Before Magento PayPal Express (in PayPal Standard) the user experience was like:

1. Address & Billing Form
2. Shipping Method
3. Payment Method
4. Agreements & Order Review
5. -> Redirect to PayPal
6. Success

After Magento has introduced its Express Payment, it looks like this:

1. Address & Billing Form
2. Shipping Method
3. Payment method
4. -> redirect to PayPal
5. <- redirect to shop
6. Agreements & Order review
7. Success

**This obviously is a really big problem. Even bigger than you might think.**

I have updated an Onlineshop with an average of 400 orders per day from PayPal Standard to PayPal Express. Before the update, there was an order cancellation rate of 0.5% per day, after choosing a payment method. that means about 1-2 people per day cancelled after they've already chosen a payment method.

After the update from PayPal Standard to PayPal Express, the cancellation rate went up to **8%**! This was measured over a time of 3 Months.
After we've installed screen recording tools, we found out that most of this people are just simply thinking they're already done after filling out their login credentials.

People also started calling the company and asking where their order is stucking at. They thought they have ordered, but they never did.

This is a really really big problem to be honest and i have no idea how to fix this. Anyone has an idea how to get back the order review before redirecting to PayPal?

BTW: Activating the "skip order review" is not working in the german market, because you always have terms & conditions, that you have to opt in before checkout.

Comment: Nice stats about cancellation rate!